# Botão quando clicado tem efeito em outro

Tags: html, css

Fiz um botão usando ID's e mesmo assim quando clicado ele da um `margin-top=10px` em ambos. Qual meu erro? Quero que ele faça efeito somente no botão que foi clicado!

```css
button{
 border: none;
 background-color: lemonchiffon;
 border-radius: 50%;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px #666;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#azul:active{
 background-color: skyblue;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px dimgray;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
#red:active{
 background-color: tomato;
 cursor: pointer;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px dimgray;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bot">
  <h2>Avalie nosso site</h2>
  <button onclick="positivo()" id="azul">
   <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" style="color: navy;"></span>
  </button>
  <button onclick="negativo()" id="red">
   <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-3x" style="color: red;"></span>
  </button>
```

Comment: Falta o JavaScript na pergunta.

Comment: Esse `margin-top=20px` deve estar em outro lugar, porque nesses seletores que você colocou na pergunta nenhum coloca 20px.

Comment: Não é necessário usar Javascript para resolver isso pelo que eu sei

Comment: não, eu simplesmente escrevi errado na hora

Comment: Se você chama no onclick uma função javascript. Como não é necessário? é possível que tenha trocado o id do elemento aonde chama o evento de clique do botão verifique no seu jascript se não trocou as ids.

Comment: O problema está no CSS. A margem do `button:active` está afetando diretamente os outros.

Comment: Eu ainda não fiz o Js do site, coloquei onclick ali para me lembrar mais tarde(tirei ele e ainda assim não adiantou)

Comment: Como eu faço para que eles não se afetem? 'margin-right' maior no button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione a propriedade `vertical-align: top` no seletor `button`, depois ajuste o `margin-top` dos botões `:active`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g1t4561/)

```css
button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #ded268;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#azul:active {
  background-color: skyblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px dimgray;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

#red:active {
  background-color: tomato;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px dimgray;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bot">
  <h2>Avalie nosso site</h2>
  <button id="azul">
    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" style="color: navy;"></span>
  </button>
  <button id="red">
    <span class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down fa-3x" style="color: red;"></span>
  </button>
```